# Как проверить два расширения?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно проверить два расширения не соединяя их а по отдельности

```
string.Concat(inputFile, "text") - Вот тут нужно добавить ещё один string.Concat(inputFile, "test")

public void FooTest(bool release, string inputFile)
{
   var test = new FileStream(release ? 
   string.Concat(inputFile, "text") : inputFile.Replace("text", "")
  .Replace("test", ""), FileMode.CreateNew);
}
```

Не знаю как можно соединить проверку с двумя (разными) расширениями.

```
string[] exts = new[] { "text", "test" };
```

Может можно как-то использовать `linq` внутри? и кинуть в `string.Concat(inputFile, exts)`

---

Мне нужно чтобы при выборе release в true, изменялись расширения файлов на text и test рандомно
Если false то расширения удаляются
Пытаюсь как-то смастерить в одну строку всё, но не могу понять как.

Comment: Вопрос не понятен, как склеить строку из 3 частей, или в чем вопрос? Проверить что, существует файл или нет, или что проверить?

Comment: Напишите поведение и результат. Нето не понятно

Comment: Что значит рандомно? При значении `true` к файлу прицеплялось рандомное расширение? Это очень странно звучит, либо я не понял ничего снова. Что метод дедает то? В примере бессмысленная кукла, которая не делает ничего.

Comment: @aepot, Да! Рандомное расширение

Comment: А зачем вам тут LINQ? Делайте нечто [такое](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jFrP4w), да и все, большего и не надо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> при выборе release в true, изменялись расширения файлов на text и test рандомно

Можно использовать специальный класс `Random`, предназначенный для рандомных дел.

```cs
private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();

public void FooTest(bool release, string inputFile)
{
    string fileName = inputFile;
    if (release)
    {
        string[] exts = new[] { "text", "test" };
        fileName += exts[rnd.Next(0, exts.Length)];
    }
    // ... fileName - нужная строка
}
```